# Reverse proxy on azure app service

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I've got the asp.net web site deployed to the Azure App Service.

I need to move out the api to another website on another url. For that I've done the reverse proxy:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="ProxyRuleApi" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^api/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://anotherApiServer/api/{R:1}"/>
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But constantly get the "500" error. So looks like App Service fails to read web.config or something.. Not sure about the problem at all.

ARR turned on.

- Anyone faced the issue?
- What I'm doing wrong?
- Am I doing it right?
- How can I trace an error? (detailed errors have been turned on and
  custom errors I've turned off).

I've even try to

```
<action type="AbortRequest" />
```

Still got 500 status.

This is an error message:

> the page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

**UPD. Solution.** 
The problem was that I've forgot about the transformation that exists in the `Web.Release.config` that Applied another rewrite rules to the `Web.Config`. So I've updated the `Web.Release.config` to include my changes into the transformation.

The generated error has been generated with IIS because it was not possible to read the `Web.config` with twi `rewrite rules` defined. Azure portal helped me to find this out. `App Service -> Diagnostic logs -> Turn them on` and after that `App Service -> Log stream`. You will see the stream of the logs.

Comment: I know that it's not an answer, but can't you use Azure Functions for that? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reverse-proxy-using-azure-functions-proxies/

Comment: Not really. That's no our case.